# What kind of join do I need for this query?

Tags: mysql, join

I always seem to have trouble with joins for some reason.  Anyway, I have a table of articles and a table of article_comments.  I want to order the rows from the articles table by the number of comments an article has.  so a row in the comments table will have a column for article id.  Right now, my query only returns rows from the articles table that has rows from the comments table linked to it(only articles that have comments).  I want to return all rows from the articles table regardless of whether or not it has a comment(you can disregard the inner join here), but I still want to be able to order the article results by the number of comments each article has, even if it is 0.  I hope you understand.

This is my current query:

```
   SELECT 
      a.article_id, a.type, 
      p.article_id, p.platform_id, 
      c.comment_id, c.article_id, COUNT(c.comment_id) AS comments
   FROM articles AS a
   INNER JOIN article_plat_assoc AS p ON a.article_id = p.article_id 
   LEFT JOIN article_comments AS c ON a.article_id = c.article_id 
   WHERE p.platform_id = 1 
   ORDER BY comments DESC
   LIMIT 15
```

Here is the SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db1e8/1/0

Comment: What's not working with the SQL you've got there?

Comment: It's not returning articles that don't have comments.  I want to return all articles even if they don't have comments.  I just want to order the articles by the number of comments they have.

Comment: I am sure this can be resolved pretty quick, but if you wanted to make a SQLFiddle, that would help us work with your tables and such to find you an optimal query

Comment: Looks correct to me... A SQLFiddle will probably help.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any entries with `comments = 0` "after" your result set? what happens if you execute that query without `LIMIT 15`?

Comment: Yeah. Looks good to me.

Comment: Ok, I've added the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have the aggregate function `Count` you need to `GROUP BY` at least one field or you will get one row back.

```
SELECT
  a.article_id, a.title, c.comment_id, c.article_id, COUNT(c.comment_id) AS comments
FROM articles AS a
LEFT JOIN article_comments AS c ON a.article_id = c.article_id
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY comments DESC
LIMIT 15
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db1e8/17)

For more information read [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)